# Microbit: Plot x y does not work when a sprite is on the screen

Tags: bbc-microbit

I have a program that aims to function like an etch-a-sketch.
If you hit A, the X coordinate will change, and if you hit B the Y coordinate will change.

I use a sprite as the 'crosshair' and pressing A+B will plot a point at the current coordinate. The problem is whenever there's a sprite on the screen plot just doesn't work.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sprites will start the microbit game engine which will render the sprites and override any kind of animation you are trying to show. I would suggest you do all the drawing with sprites and the game engine.

This would mean that when you press A+B it would create a new sprite for the location. Any example of doing this is:

[image: Example sketcher code]

Comment: Arrays, I'll have to look into those. What's the code block about absolutes do? Does it find the nearest rotation of 90 degrees?

Comment: `absolute of` returns the number without the sign. i.e -90 is returned as 90. I am using it as a simple test for if the sprite is travelling in the `x` or `y` direction. https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/math